# Cannot install PhantomJS for use in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, installation

Here is the entire transaction... at least the part I can see. I have several npm packages installed and they all work, except phantomjs (not phantom). Here is the entire transaction... at least the part I can see.

```
> npm install phantomjs
\
> phantomjs@1.9.18 install C:\server\nodejs\node_modules\phantomjs
> node install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\server\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\server\\nodejs   \\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phantomjs"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.18 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.18 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\server\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

nodemon (and node) commands work on folder C:\server\nodejs. other packages are installed here and end up in the subfolder: C:\server\nodejs\node_modules. Looks like the package is trying to run "node install.js" but the directory is wrong..

seems like I have been reading everything I can find but after couple of days I have to ask: ANYONE KNOWS WHAT IS GOING ON?

Comment: Do you have node installed globally though? Like can you use it from any directory?

Answer (score -1):

Attention: there is a package called phantomjs and a package called phantom. There are not the same package. The main phantomjs is appropriately the phantomjs package. Phantom is a wrapper for phantomjs that creates a bridge  (simply: makes  phantomjs work with nodejs). I had installed the phantom thinking I was using phantomjs. To use phantom, you must first install phantomjs.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It is the OP explaining what caused their problem.